# Active group connection Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

after trying connection to Mysql from PHP i get error:
You have specified an invalid database connection group.
I created one user and set privileges, set password, but did not specify group

How to set active group Mysql or change?

Comment: You are probably not loading the right database group or your configuration is not correct. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309468/you-have-specified-an-invalid-database-connection-group-codeigniter-error).

Comment: I am sure that my password and user name, db name are correct. I tested it from >mysql console

Comment: Now I set $active_group = "default"; and error mysql disappeared, but page is white, I use codeigniter

Comment: When you have a white page, it's most likely because of a fatal error somewhere.  Check if you have an error_log file, if you have any logs, debug your application or start commenting out code until you find the problematic line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your `config/database.php` file should look -

```
$active_group = 'default';      // Your active group
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'hostname';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```